# Does having FaceID or touchID in your app when app enters background stop audio playing in background?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avplayer, face-id

I have a Biometrics for FaceID/TouchID that activities whenever the app enters background. I already have the app configured to play audio in the background, but FaceID/TouchID seems to stop all background activity, such as audio. Is this the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer yes it does. If FaceID and TouchID is activated at AppDidEnterBackground; basically whenever the user leaves the app, it will stop the audio. Has not nothing to do with background fetch since the audio file was already downloaded. codeherk's answer is accurate if anyone is looking for how to play audio in the background.

Answer (score 0):

By default, audio is always stopped when entering the background. To enable it, you must configure your app **Capabilities**.

Click on your app target > Capabilites > Background Modes
then set on Audio, Airplay, and Picture in Picture.

[image]

Add this code on the line before the audio is played:

```
do {
   try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [.mixWithOthers, .allowAirPlay]) // enable player back
   try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true) // set session to active
} catch {
   print(error)
}
```

Comment: I already do that. It plays in background when not using FaceID or TouchID. But once there is FaceID or TouchID activated, it doesn't play in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Also check the Background fetch mode in capabilities.